# Finding MongoDB CPU usage,Disk Utilization , RAM using Query /Command

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to get the status of CPU usage and Disk utilisation through query/command for the cluster running on Mongodb Atlas.
I just want to make sure that CPU & Disk utilisation are under threshold before hitting Query/Command.

Comment: Have you checked  [`serverStatus()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.serverStatus/#db.serverstatus--) command?

Comment: serverStatus() command gives RAM ,but I could not find CPU usage and Disk utilization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using instance type [M10+ clusters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/real-time-performance-panel/), you can enable **Real-Time Performance Panel (RTPP)** in the dashboard to monitor the CPU Usage and Disk Utilization metrics in MongoDB Atlas, otherwise there is no way to see these two metrics.